Wave Experiment Method
Hello I am conducting an experiment to see how the tension, given by a hanging mass, affects the resonant frequency of a string. I would like to conduct 3 trials at 5 different tension forces/weights.
My current thought on the procedure is:

Put on all the weight
Change the function generator until it reaches the first harmonic pattern
Record the frequency
Remove some weights
Find the new frequency to the first harmonic
Repeat

However I am wondering whether this method could be wrong because for each tension force, wouldn't I just be getting the same frequency? How exactly will I get 3 trials out of each  tension force as the machine will already be tuned, and no further adjustment is needed? There will be no variation in the frequency for each tension force.
It would just look something like:
Force 50N
Trial 1: 10 Hz
Trial 2: 10 Hz
Trial 3: 10 Hz
I am not sure if I explained my issue correctly so please let me know if further explanation is needed.

Fix the tension and look for the resonance position by starting with the frequency lower than the resonant frequency. Repeat by start above the resonant frequency. Repeat again by starting below the resonant frequency, $\dots$

great thank you!
